# Does conditional fields with radio buttons in react forms work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am creating a form with 'occupation' field as radio button. There are two options for occupation-i.e. self employed and service. According to the choice the user makes for occupation, I am showing different fields of the form. I am using if-else for this conditional rendering. Code works well for if-part but doesn't work for the else-part. I am attaching my code for reference.

```
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                      <input 
                        type= "radio"
                        id= "fatherService"
                        name= "fatherOccupation"
                        value = "service"
                        checked={fatherOccupation === "service"}
                        onChange={handleFatherOccupation}
                      />
                      <label htmlFor="fatherService">Service</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <input 
                        type= "radio"
                        id= "fatherSelfEmployed"
                        name= "fatherOccupation"
                        value = "selfEmployed"
                        checked={fatherOccupation === "selfEmployed"}
                        onChange={handleFatherOccupation}
                      />
                      <label htmlFor="fatherSelfEmployed">Self Employed</label>
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {fatherOccupation === "service" ? (
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <label>Company Name:</label>
                    <input 
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control p-2"
                      id="fatherCompanyName"
                      name="fatherCompanyName"
                      {...register("fatherCompanyName", {
                        required:"Please enter father's company name",  
                      })}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>  
              ) : (
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <label>Type of Business:</label>
                    <input 
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control p-2"
                      id="fatherTypeOfBusiness"
                      name="fatherTypeOfBusiness"
                      {...register("fatherTypeOfBusiness", {
                        required:"Please enter father's type of business",  
                      })}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
```

Comment: show us `handleFatherOccupation`

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67519704/2015452). Check the CodeSandbox, i think it should answer your question too.

Comment: Thank you @knoefel, that answered my question! :)