# React Hook Form Dynamic Require

Tags: validation, react-hook-form

Good Day All,

Im using react hook form and I want set required dynamically on one text-input. I have a useState that tracks the delivery method and radio buttons that update that state. And then the text-input required should be based dynamically on that state. So if the delivery method is "Delivery" we require your address if its "Pickup" we dont require your address. I hope that makes sense.

In the code below the show/hide functionality works as expected however the dynamic require does not.

```
const [ delivery, setDelivery ] = useState(false);

<InfoBlock>
  <strong>Delivery Method</strong>
  <RadioGroup>
    <RadioBlock>
      <input type="radio" id="pickup" name="pickup" {...register("deliveryMethod", {required: true})} 
        value="pickup" onClick={() => setDelivery(false)} />
      <h5>Pickup</h5>
    </RadioBlock>                
    <RadioBlock>
      <input type="radio" id="deliver" name="delivery" {...register("deliveryMethod", {required: true})}  
        value="delivery" onClick={() => setDelivery(true)} />
      <h5>Delivery</h5>
    </RadioBlock>                   
  </RadioGroup>
</InfoBlock>
<ErrorMsg>
  {errors.deliveryMethod && errors.deliveryMethod.type === 'required' && "Please select delivery method"}
</ErrorMsg>

{delivery ? 
  <div>
    <InfoBlock>
      <strong>Address</strong>
      **<input type="text" id="address" name="address" 
        {...register("address", {required: delivery })}  />**
    </InfoBlock>
    <ErrorMsg>
      {errors.address && errors.address.type === 'required' && "Address is required"}
    </ErrorMsg>            
  </div> : null}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You don't need `useState` here, as you can use RHF for handling the state of your radio input value - you can just use `watch`, provided by `useForm`, to watch for changes of that field
2. As you conditionally render the 'address' input only for a certain delivery method, you can also just set `required` to `true` for the rules of that field

There is one important thing: since v7 there is no automatically removal of fields which will unmount (in your case, due to conditional rendering). So for now, you have to unregister the field manually. This is why in the CodeSandbox there is the `unregister` call, when clicking the 'pickup' radio option.

However, there is currently a [discussion](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/4783) ongoing, as this new behaviour brings disadvantages in some cases (such as conditional rendering of fields). So maybe it will be possible again in the future to unregister fields automatically on unmount.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I will try it out and let evryone know if I manage to get it right :)

Comment: Awesome I just tried it out and it worked, thanks knoefel you're the man. So for anyone else who runs into this just follow the sandbox ;)

Comment: Imnot a frequent user od stackoverflow...How do I do that ?